Optimizing function using multiprocessing.Pool()
I'm new in the multiprocessing topic. I am using a powerful machine with a lot of cores and I would like to use all the available cores.
This is the original function, which resolves the task really slow:
def get_multimodal_poi_directness(to_bus_stop_graph, bus_stop_graph, from_bus_stop_graph, start_node, target_nodes, start_time,
                                  weight_threshold, mode):

    reachable_nodes = set()

    bus_node, path_length = get_bus_station_from_isochrone(start_node)

    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=weight_threshold)

    if path_length > weight_threshold:
        return set()

    # Step 3: Find all reachable nodes from the nearest bus stop node within the remaining weight
    current_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=path_length)
    remaining_time = weight_threshold - path_length

    reachable_nodes_dict = reachable_nodes_via_bus_network(bus_stop_graph, bus_node, remaining_time, current_time, end_time, mode=mode)
    reachable_nodes.update(reachable_nodes_dict.keys())
    # Step 4: Find all reachable nodes from the bus stop nodes to POIs
    all_reachable_nodes = reachable_nodes_to_pois(from_bus_stop_graph, reachable_nodes_dict, end_time)

    reachable_nodes.update(all_reachable_nodes)
    # Step 5: Calculate the number of POIs reachable from the start node
    # node_attributes = nx.get_node_attributes(from_bus_stop_graph, 'poi')
    # poi_count = sum(node_attributes.get(node, 0) for node in all_reachable_nodes)

    return reachable_nodes


This is the modified function, using multiprocessing.Pool()

def worker(args):
return reachable_nodes_via_bus_network(\*args)

def get_multimodal_poi_directness_cpu(to_bus_stop_graph, bus_stop_graph, from_bus_stop_graph, start_node, target_nodes, start_time,
weight_threshold, mode):

    reachable_nodes = set()
    
    bus_node, path_length = get_bus_station_from_isochrone(start_node)
    
    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=weight_threshold)
    
    if path_length > weight_threshold:
        return set()
    
    # Step 3: Find all reachable nodes from the nearest bus stop node within the remaining weight
    current_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=path_length)
    remaining_time = weight_threshold - path_length
    
    
    args = (bus_stop_graph, bus_node, remaining_time, current_time, end_time, mode)
    
    
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        reachable_nodes_dict = pool.map(worker, [args])[0]
    
    reachable_nodes.update(reachable_nodes_dict.keys())
    
    # Step 4: Find all reachable nodes from the bus stop nodes to POIs
    all_reachable_nodes = reachable_nodes_to_pois(from_bus_stop_graph, reachable_nodes_dict, end_time)
    
    reachable_nodes.update(all_reachable_nodes)
    
    return reachable_nodes

I've tested the new function and its slower than before. The main goal is to run reachable_nodes_via_bus_network more efficiently.

